# The operator ! is undefined for the argument type(s) Boolean

Tags: java, jsp, precompile

I am trying to precompile my jsp's, but I am getting the below error.
I am not sure why I am getting this error. As far as I know from JDK 1.5 onwards the auto boxing will happen and this should not be an issue. We use the Jasper of Jboss 4.1 any insight to this why this is happening will be helpful for us. I just want to confirm two points.

1. If we are using jdk >1.5 then, by any chance whether this issue will occur?
2. How can we verify the version of jasper we are using?
3. Whether Japser will use jdk in path to per compile JSP?

Also the interesting fact is, this is happening when we try to pre-compile the JSP's. The functionality was working fine, when we deployed with out pre-compiling. This means Jboss was able to compile with out any issues, only the precompiling is failing.

I am not getting any clue on this error, please help.

Exception

> /opt/app/build//precompile/motor/testing/org/apache/jsp/presultblock/reading/readingdriver_jsp.java
>   (at line 116) [javac] Boolean isTest = false; [javac] ^^^^^ [javac]
>   Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to Boolean [javac]
>   ---------- [javac] 2. ERROR in /opt/app/build//precompile/motor/testing/org/apache/jsp/presultblock/reading/readingdriver_jsp.java
>   (at line 257) [javac] isTest = true; [javac] ^^^^ [javac] Type
>   mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to Boolean [javac] ----------
>   [javac] 3. ERROR in
>   /opt/app/build//precompile/motor/testing/org/apache/jsp/presultblock/reading/readingdriver_jsp.java
>   (at line 414) [javac] if(!isTest){ [javac] ^^^^^^^ [javac] The
>   operator ! is undefined for the argument type(s) Boolean [javac]
>   ---------- [javac] 3 problems (3 errors)

---

Comment: Show us the JSP and Java code that is causing this problem.

Comment: Plz check how are you pre-compiling

Answer (score 0):

Clearly your JBoss 4.1 is using a JDK < 1.5. Check your installation.

Comment: Yes it is using using Jdk 1.5, I am not having any clue on why this is happening.

Comment: Also the interesting fact is, this is happening when we try to pre-compile the JSP's. The functionality was working fine, when we deployed with out pre-compiling. This means Jboss was able to compile with out any issues, only the precompiling is failing.

Comment: Your symptomes could be explained by you doing the JSP precompilation using a JDK that doesn't support autoboxing ... and a different JDK to run JBoss.

Comment: @Adam No, it isn't using JDK 1.5. Your IDE is using 1.5 which is why it works when you precompile. JBoss clearly isn't.